# SQL Server 2012 Backups Not Compressing

Tags: sql-server, backup, compression

We recently upgraded from SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. After doing this I noticed that our DB backups were barely compressing at all. Our 22gb DB was compressing down to about 4gb before upgrading to 2012 and after the upgrade our 22gb DB is only compressing down to 19gb. I've checked and double checked the compression setting on the server and all of my backup jobs and compression is turned on. Any ideas on what may be going on?

Comment: The server default can be overridden.  Are you running your backups via script?  If so, can you post?  Or, if you're using a maintenance plan have you double checked the plan's specific compression setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was due to also enabling TDE encryption. With TDE enabled the backups compress a very small amount.